# Vertically change points position in exam class

Tags: vertical-alignment, exam

I was trying to fit my exam on two pages so I added a negative vertical space after an equation. The problem now is that the next paragraph is closer to the equation (which I intented to do) but the points won't move and are now located next to the first line of the next paragraph (which I didn't intend to do). Is there a way to move the points upwards as well?

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pointsdroppedatright

\begin{questions}

\question
\begin{parts}
    \part[5] Solve for $x$:
        $$2x+1=0$$
        \vspace{-6mm}
        \droppoints
    \part[2]
        \lipsum[2]
        \droppoints
\end{parts}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `$$` environment is deprecated.
You should use the `align` or `equation` environment.

Now to your problem. I believe the points should be next to your question and not next to your equation. If I remove the `vspace` the points are below the equation which looks ugly as well.
I just placed `droppoints` in front of your question.

```
\part[5] Solve for $x$:
    \droppoints
    \begin{equation*}
        2x+1=0
    \end{equation*}
    \vspace{-6mm}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I want the points to be at the end of the question on the right hand side. Is there a way to control the vertical alignment of the points?